# Access required to change shower drain

Tags: plumbing, shower, leak, drain, accessibility

I'm not handy so excuse the rough description.  I think that my shower drain is leaking.  There is water in the trap and the leak stopped, so I think it's something about how the drain connects to the shower.  I'm not likely to fix this myself so I called a plumber.  They told me that they will only fix the issue "if they have access".  What kind of access are they going to need?  Will they need to access the shower from below?  Or can they fix the issue from above the drain only?  It seems like a pretty standard 1 piece shower.  I'm trying to get an idea of any demo required.  Thanks.

[image]

Comment: A plumber is usually busy and they cost money per hour.  Leaks usually happen in drain pipes or the water pipes.  The plumber needs access to both of these systems to find an unknown leak, one underneath and the other in a wall.  If leak is in drain pipes, they need access from underneath, leak might just be at joint of shower base and could be fixed there.

Comment: What is below the shower?  If it's another room's ceiling then that might need to be opened up to get access to the plumbing.

Comment: The living room is below the shower.  But we are planning to remodel the bathroom soon.  If they need access below we're just as likely to start the demo early than put a hole in the ceiling.

Comment: Why do you think the shower is leaking? Are there water stains on the ceiling below? If you cut out that area of the ceiling (it will need to be replaced anyway due to water damage), that will provide some if not all the access a plumber will need to address the leak.